# How geo URL Scheme link with multiple coordinates?

Tags: android, html

I'm trying to open a routing app (not google map) when user click on a link in android phone.

i don't want to use google map, so i make a link with geo URL Scheme like this:

`<a href="geo:34,48">`

and its work fine, but i want to make a link with multiple coords. for showing origin and destination coords on app.

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Answer (score 0):

I send second point with query parameter "q". now below link open routing applications like "here", with two origin and destination points. its work for two point but for more points i have no idea.

```
<a href="geo:34.80,48.50?q=34.81,48.52">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).